# Show Progress Dialog before loading ListView contents

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I'm reading data from a file -> saving into DB -> Loading my Custom ListView by fetching data from DB.. While Fetching and Saving Data to DB i want to ProgressDialog to appear on my screen i tried these two type 
but its not working

Type 1:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = AlertDialog.show(CommoditiesListScreen.this, "Importing...");

// importing data from file
// Saving data to the DB

alertDialog.dismiss();
```

Type 2:

```
 UiDialog uiDialog = new UiDialog(CommoditiesListScreen.this);
 CommoditiesListScreen.this.runOnUiThread(uiDialog);
 AlertDialog alertDialog = AlertDialog.show(CommoditiesListScreen.this, "Importing...");
 alertDialog.getWindow().makeActive();


// importing data from file
// Saving data to the DB

uiDialog.stopDialog();
alertDialog.dismiss();
```

I tried in both ways it not working, ProgressDialog is not appearing on the screen, Anything else i've add or any modification i've to do in my cod eplease help me...

**Note: When Forgot call dismiss(); in Type 1 Progress appears after ListView loaded and it spins for infinite time..**

Comment: use async task for fetching ,saving in DB and setting in listview. in pre execution of async task start you alert dialog and in post execution dismiss your dialog

Comment: Thanks, Is there any Thread problem in my code, i'm not able to pointout plz help me

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ideal situation to use `AsyncTask` where you can show your `dialog` in the method `onPreExecute()`, perform your background operations (reading data from a file -> saving into DB ) in the method `doInBackground()` and load and display your list in the method `onPostExecute()`.